# How do you have a timer on bot v4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, bots

I want to use a timer for 5 second to display the message but I get an error. It is in Node.Js.

Is there a way to solve this issue? Thanks

```
     const HELP_INTENT = 'Help';
     async onTurn(context) {
     Switch(Intent){
       case HELP_INTENT:
       var reply =  MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Testing','Running'],`How do we help you?`);
     setInterval(() => {
       await dc.context.sendActivity(reply);
       }, 5000);
       break;
       case NONE_INTENT:
       default:
           await dc.context.sendActivity(`Sorry I do not understand you.`);
       break;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this

```
const HELP_INTENT = 'Help';
         async onTurn(context) {
         Switch(Intent){
           case HELP_INTENT:
           var reply =  MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Testing','Running'],`How do we help you?`);
           await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(
            dc.context.sendActivity(reply)
           ), 5000);
           break;
           case NONE_INTENT:
           default:
               await dc.context.sendActivity(`Sorry I do not understand you.`);
           break;
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I got this error. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
(node:11020) [DEP0018]

Comment: I edited the code. Do you think that's the reason why? Thanks

Comment: @khmerforce when you use await inside of function. You have to replace all parent function to async function. for example async function(){
 var reply =  MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Testing','Running'],`How do we help you?`);
 setInterval(async function(){await dc.context.sendActivity(reply);}, 5000);
}

Comment: setInterval(() => {
              var reply =  MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Testing','Running'],`How do we help you?`);
       await dc.context.sendActivity(reply);
       }, 5000);
       break;

I tried this and still got the same error. Not sure why.

Comment: @khmerforce i update pls check. if it doesnt work dont worry we'll reach success anyway

Comment: @khmerforce  did you try like this

setInterval(async () => {
          var reply =  MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Testing','Running'],`How do we help you?`);
          await dc.context.sendActivity(reply);
          }, 5000);

Comment: IT WORKS THANKS! THE CODE YOU PUT ABOVE

Comment: You're a life savor. How did you figured it out?

Comment: @khmerforce this code work ?(if its, you must all parent functions put  async ) >
setInterval(async () => { var reply = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Testing','Running'],How do we help you?); await dc.context.sendActivity(reply); }, 5000);

Comment: await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(
            dc.context.sendActivity(reply)
           ), 5000);

This one works. I'm not sure how you know it.